# .NET Library for reading video frames

Tags: .net, streaming, video-processing

Is there a library written in .NET that allows me to read a video frame by frame?

Sample usage could be as follows:

```
Video vid = Video.Open("test.avi");
foreach (Bitmap bmp in vid.Frames)
      PictureBox1.Picture = bmp;
```

Comment: Some good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956/c-whats-the-easiest-library-to-open-video-file

No pain - no gain. Also, the avi file format is supposedly very simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Microsoft's [IMediaDet interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms785892(VS.85).aspx), specifically the  GetBitmapBits and WriteBitmapBits methods.

This article on CodeProject deomonstrates:
[Extract Frames from Video Files](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx)