# How to split video to frames using Qt?

Tags: qt, video, h.264, phonon, mpeg-4

I'd like to load the video file (H.264 and MPEG-4) and split it in 2 parts for example.  I want it split on the 30th second - but I'd like to save frames entirely. 
So, are there any methods to do it? I looked into the Phonon but I didn't see anything useful for this issue.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956/c-whats-the-easiest-library-to-open-video-file