# C++ video processing loop

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I want to write an application which takes a video stream and in the cycle do processing frames and fragments of audio.

I saw such loop [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffplay_8c-source.html):

I saw on the forums some solution with pipes [here](https://superuser.com/questions/999400/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-extract-live-stream-into-a-sequence-of-mp4)

Is it any library wrapper on ffmpeg/avlib which I could just write my callback without tones of spaghetti around like [here](https://github.com/erikkaashoek/Comskip/blob/master/mpeg2dec.c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ : What's the easiest library to open video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956/c-whats-the-easiest-library-to-open-video-file)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using Opencv for this. It takes care of a lot of the problems with video streams for you and allows processing on the individual frames.

Answer (score 0):

Here simple and easy to follow examples:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples

I'm assuming you have experienced C++ programmer so these examples will give you a good start (btw, examples in C).